# Is there a van Laarhoven representation of `Optional`

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, lenses, monocle-scala

Many types of optics have a van Laarhoven representation.

For example, a `Lens` of type `Lens s t a b`  can be represented as:

```
 Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

Similarly a `Traversal`, can be represented in a similar way, swapping the `Functor` constraint for `Applicative`:

```
 Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

Several optics frameworks, such as [Monocle](http://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle/) and [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/optics/optional/) define a type called `Optional`.

[In Monocle's Optics heirarchy](https://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle/optics.html) `Optional` fits between `Lens` and `Traversal`

As I understand it: If a `Traversal` is like a `Lens` that may have *zero to many* targets, then an `Optional` is like a `Lens` that may have *zero to one* targets.

In Monocle, `Optional` is defined as a pair of functions:

```
getOrModify :: s -> Either t a 
set :: (b, s) -> t
```

[Comments in the Monocle source code](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/monocle/Optional.scala) suggest that it's also possible to represent an `Optional` "as a weaker `PLens` and weaker `PPrism`"

Is it possible to represent an `Optional` as a van Laarhoven function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There would be a way to represent it if the Functor/Applicative/Monad hierarchy were more fine-grained. In particular:

```
class Functor f => Pointed f where
    pure :: a -> f a

type Optional s t a b = forall f. Pointed f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

Note that the type would probably be named `Affine` in the lens library if that was neatly in the class hierarchy.

Comment: This is conveniently completely fine for my use case, which is a "just for fun" Scala Optics Library where I've written the Functor Hierarchy from scratch, and can therefore do whatever I like with it.


Am I right in thinking that this suggests that If I also had a another type-class between `Functor` and `Applicative` with `liftA2`, but no pure, then that would define an optic with _one to many_ targets? Does this have a name?

Comment: It does suggest that. I have no idea what the optic would be called.

Comment: @Joe That intermediate class is called `Apply` in the "semigroupoids" package. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.3/docs/Data-Functor-Apply.html#t:Apply

Comment: ... and the corresponding optic in the `lens` package is called [`Traversal1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t:Traversal1)

Comment: @Carl How can we verify that this `type Optional s t a b` is indeed the correct representation for that optic, and that all the appropriate laws hold? This seems like a magical trick. Why was it `Pointed` and not, say, `Copointed`? For another given optic, how can we guess the correct profunctor representation?

Comment: @winitzki If you write a bunch of van Laarhoven lenses and traversals by hand (very highly recommended - they're not magic), you eventually get a handle on how the operations correspond to the number of targets present in a data structure. `fmap` handles a structure with a single target. `pure` handles a structure with no targets. `(<*>)` combines substructures that have each handled targets. From this you can observe that something with only `fmap` and `pure` will let you handle 0 or 1 targets, but not more than 1. And that's `Pointed`.

Comment: As for `Profunctor` optics... Dunno. I've never really seen the appeal, so I haven't written enough of them by hand to see what the blocks are. My impression from the little I have done is that they don't seem as amenable to piecewise breakdowns. (That impression may be wrong.)